# database design : Inventory with multiple item units ( wholesale and retail )

Tags: database-design

I have designed a db for drug ( pharmacy ) store which will sell medicine both wholesale and retail. There are some medicine that can be sold in multiple units, for example, strip, capsule and vial of medicine. Basically, each medicine can be sold in more than one unit. Here is my db:

[image]

I have an inventory movement records  that record the specific stock used to fill each order. if a medicine’s base unit is set to vial, and It has some records with vial in the inventory movement, and after a period of time, I want to sell that medicine with capsule unit, at this time, how do I record this to the inventory movement ? And how do I calculate the stocks from inventory ?

If I update the item_unit record to set the data like following:

[image]

And I need to scan whole InventoryMocement table to update the base unit to the new one ( capsule ) and re-calculate the quantity with the multiplier. Is this reasonable ?

Is there any flaws in my design ? Does anyone have any ideas (or examples)?

Comment: Is this homework or a hobby project?  If you've never done this, COTS is probably the way to go.  Also, don't stick a row pointer on everything, you'll make a mess.

Comment: @bbaird It's an on going project, not a homework. we want to build our own inventory tracking system for our own pharmacy.

Comment: I would recommend finding an off the shelf solution